# $\sigma$-algebra corresponding to closure of span of random variables in Hilbert space

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, hilbert-spaces

If $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is a probability space and $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is the Hilbert space of finite-variance random variables on this space, we can consider, for any sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ the closed subspace $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{G}, \mathbb{P})$. Then we have the well-known result:

$\mathbb{E}[Y||\mathcal{G}]=P_{L^2(\mathcal{G})}(Y)$

For linear estimation, we want to consider $P_{L^2(\mathcal{H})}(Y)$ for $\mathcal{H} = \overline{span}\{X_1,...,X_n\}$, where $X_k$ are random variables in $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{G}, \mathbb{P})$. Clearly, this is not the conditional expectation wrt $\mathcal{G}$. I'm struggling to understand, however, with respect to *what* $\sigma$-algebra then this is the expectation. My lecturer quickly mentioned something about the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{H}$ serving this purpose, but I'm not really clear on what that means. Moreover, he uses $\sigma\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ anyway throughout his notes to denote the filtration, but that doesn't seem right to me, as it would seem to imply $P_{L^2(\mathcal{H})}(Y) = \mathbb{E}[Y||X_1,...,X_n]$ which is not true in general. Any ideas?